# Хотел собрать минимальную систему Linux, но при запуске он выдает ошибку

Tags: linux, ядро

Захотел я значит собрать минимальную систему линукс. Собрал, в итоге получил два файла. initrd.img и vmlinuz. Запускаю я всё это дело в qemu следующей командой:
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel vmlinuz -initrd initrd.img -nographic  -append 'console=ttyS0'

И после запуска выдает ошибку:

```
[    4.844559] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    4.845955] 0b00         1048575 sr0 
[    4.846232]  driver: sr
[    4.847642] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    4.848312] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.14.336 #1
[    4.848312] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS Arch Linux 1.16.3-1-1 04/01/2014
[    4.848312] Call Trace:
[    4.848312]  dump_stack+0x50/0x63
[    4.848312]  panic+0xde/0x22a
[    4.848312]  mount_block_root+0x174/0x1fe
[    4.848312]  prepare_namespace+0x136/0x16c
[    4.848312]  kernel_init_freeable+0x1b6/0x1c4
[    4.848312]  ? rest_init+0x9a/0x9a
[    4.848312]  kernel_init+0x5/0xf7
[    4.848312]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[    4.848312] Kernel Offset: 0x35000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    4.848312] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Знающие люди, скажите мне пожалуйста что с этим делать?

Показываю что положил в файл initrd
!Спойлер, я новичок в деле сборки linux поэтому не убивайте меня с первой же ошибки))

Я туда положил следующие папки:

```
etc
lib
dev
mnt
proc
tmp
root
```

Создал эти файлы:

```
/etc/inittab
/etc/fstab
/etc/mtab
/etc/rc.d/rc.S
/etc/profile
/etc/shell
```

Судя по ответам мне надо какой-то init писать да?

Comment: а дальше что хотели сделать? Ядро вот не знает, что вы от него хотите при отсутствии root fs

Comment: @Мелкий в initrd должен быть минимальный инит

Comment: Что там в initrd положили показывайте

Comment: а, вижу, ошибся, думал Please append a correct "root=" как раз после загрузки initramfs ругается на отсутствующий параметр, но в этом случае другой текст используется.

Comment: @eri - я изменил вопрос, там написано что я положил в initrd

Comment: Тебе наверное надо в сторону проекта `LFS` посмотреть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно закинуть программу `init`.

Линукс не нашел её в initrd и полез искать её в root.

Для больших линуксов это systemd.

Для минимальных  систем это или *скрипт на баше* (как в опенврт) или самостоятельный `init` который исполнит `inittab`.

Желательно закинуть хоть какой-то шелл чтоб взаимодействовать с системой.

`init` и `sh` можно сделать на базе [busybox](https://busybox.net/).

посмотрите аналогичный проект https://github.com/t00sh/vm-make